# Difference between official and non-official moderator

Tags: discussion, questions, moderators

What's the difference between *access to moderator tool(which requires 10000 rep point)* and *being an moderator(official moderator)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 10k user has access to a number of tools that really just assist with the utility of their normal privileges - access to close vote lists, access to deleted questions, overviews of general problem areas, and vision to the cookie-cutter flags like "not-an-answer". You can see a general overview of these privileges [at this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users/4576#4576).

A moderator with a diamond has all the privileges of all reputation levels (regardless of their own reputation), as well as a number of additional capabilities to assist on a much greater degree of management. These include that their close/delete votes are binding (one vote will always settle the action rather than requiring 5), they can lock and protect posts, and they can suspend problem users. You can read up a description of all of the diamond powers [at this other Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/what-abilities-are-moderators-given/100153#100153).

Comment: I've also noticed that I get notifications of edits that need approval (I don't recall seeing this before I hit 10k) and can act on those edits

Comment: Ah, yes, that is also one of the effects you get, though it falls in line with "assistance", as the approval of edits has been available as an earlier privilege and this is just letting you see them easier. I guess the post hasn't been updated with that particular tidbit yet. Good to point that out!

Answer (score 3):

I'd say check out

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges

and

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

to compare and contrast.